# Returning from StartActivityForResult opening Same Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I am not sure what the problem in my code, today i face an strange problem when calling startActivityForResult.

Below is my code -

From Activity A when i call -

```
startActivityForResult(intent,122);
```

Then Activity B opens as desire. 
Now while i am calling below line of code from activity B -

```
 Intent in = getIntent();
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,in);
 finish();
```

Then its open same Activity B.

I debugged code and found that onCreate() of Activity B called when i am finishing activity B.

Any one can sort out this problem much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Change this Intent in = getIntent(); to Intent in = new Intent();

Comment: Tried your solution but same result

Comment: is the code reaching your onActivityResult in A  and what does it look like?

Comment: Very first time it goes to onActivityResult  of class A, but when reopen activity B and  calling finish from B , onCreate  of activity B is called instead of onActivityResult of class A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this...

```
 Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code in Activity B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(requestCode, intent);
finish();
```